# JVM Error for Java Service Wrapper

Tags: java, jvm, wrapper, java-service-wrapper

This appears in a log file when I try to start a service I just installed as a windows service using the JSWrapper:

STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/06/16 13:55:57 | Launching a JVM...

ERROR  | wrapper  | 2011/06/16 13:55:57 | JVM exited while loading the application.

STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/06/16 13:55:57 | JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.

STATUS | wrapper  | 2011/06/16 13:55:58 | <-- Wrapper Stopped

Can anyone tell me what needs to be done to fix this issue? I have java installed and paths set correctly in environment variables. Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

since there is also no output of the JVM from the Wrapper's initialization, I suppose there is sth wrong with your wrapper.java.command...

can you please enable debug mode by setting wrapper.debug=true in your conf file? 
you should see the command line of the JVM the Wrapper is trying to execute.

If you don't see any problem in both places, please post the output and let me have a look at it...

cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Your application is throwing some exception while starting up.  You need to find a log of what's being thrown, or else set an catch-all exception handler for the program to print a log.  You do that by having your main find out its thread group, and then setting a ThreadGroup [uncaught exception handler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28%29) for it.

Comment: The application works fine if i just run it from eclipse. The problem is when i wrap it (I've wrapped other jars before) and make it a service, it just won't start up.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to answer your question without more info. Try logging everything during application startup, and isolate the part of code which exits JVM. Also, check Java version which are used by JSW - is it the same as the one you use in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I checked some other forum. I completelly uninstall every java version on my computer, and reinstall (in this order) java 8, then java 8 jdk, then java 8 jre. And everything works fine now. Eclipse doesn't require any change or anything, and my app works fine.

Comment: what is your question?